# Rosh Chodesh and Six Working Days pt.2

Tags: rosh-chodesh-new-month

Within Exodus 20 it says ”Six days you labour, and shall do all your work,” so is Rosh Chodesh included in these six working days, but it’s optional to work on it? Or is it not apart of the six working days?

Comment: it is a "working day" as there is no explicit, biblical commandment to refrain from working on it https://dinonline.org/2018/10/09/doing-melacha-on-rosh-chodesh/

Comment: "Part 2" or duplicate of https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/131180/rosh-chodesh-and-the-six-working-days?rq=1 ?

Answer (score 2):

Rosh Chodesh is only a festival for women, which they got as a reward for not participating in the making of the golden calf. However, I don’t believe that the possuk is including all the Yomim Tovim etc, as it doesn’t say “4.86549743 days a week you should work on average”